# Marker click event is not firing

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have taken on some code already in production and I have a problem with some markers not having a click event attached to them.

To try and get this working I have stripped back the code and just implemented the basic example shown in this page - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple, inside the structure of my current code.

However, this doesn't work, the marker is set but the click event is not attached.

Attaching a click event to the map works.

Does anybody have any suggestions about what could be causing this?

```
init() {
    this.loadScript(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=${this.apiClient}`);
}

loadScript(url) {
    const script = document.createElement('script');

    script.type = 'text/javascript';

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.initMap();
    }, 500);
}

initMap() {
    const myLatlng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

    const map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement, {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng
    });

    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Click to zoom'
    });

    map.addListener('center_changed', function() {
        // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
        // marker.
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
        }, 3000);
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function markerClick() {
        map.setZoom(8);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    });
}
```

Comment: Not seeing where you calling the init(), may be better to embed the script in html bottom of the page as in your example.. Please upload your html..

Comment: The posted code works ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/sez2wujo/)), please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I have found that the code I posted and works (as demonstrated by _geocodezip_ the problem is with the `client` param in the url.  If I remove this everything works (but with a map that says for development purposes only as a watermark.)  I am running this through Adobe Experience Manager 6.4 and think a recent version upgrade may have caused this issue.  I'll investigate further and post updates when I have them.

Comment: In the end this was fixed simply by my client logging in to their Google Maps account.  We were checking everything was ok there and it seemed so.  The next time I refreshed the map it suddenly worked.  In the end it was a wild goose chase, the code was correct, it seems the account had been blocked somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I make a few change and works

```js
const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Click to zoom',
            icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/parking_lot_maps.png'
        });

        map.addListener('center_changed', function () {
            // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
            // marker.
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
            }, 3000);
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function () {
            map.setZoom(8);
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
```